# The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http' when calling web service

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to call a SharePoint web service from a CRM workflow using custom C# code.  However when I run my code, I get the following error:

`The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.
Parameter name: via`

Here is the offending code:

```
#region Set up security binding and service endpoint
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Ntlm;
EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(endpointAddress);
#endregion

#region Create the client and supply appropriate credentials
CopySPContents.CopyService.SharepointFileServiceClient client = new CopySPContents.CopyService.SharepointFileServiceClient(binding, endpoint);              
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;              
#endregion

#region Call the web service and trace its response
String response = client.CopyFolderContentsAcrossSites(sourceSiteURL, sourceFolderURL, destinationSiteURL, destinationFolderURL);
#endregion
```

The error gets thrown on the line `String response = client.CopyFolderContentsAcrossSites(sourceSiteURL, sourceFolderURL, destinationSiteURL, destinationFolderURL);` where the client's method is called.

Thanks for any help,
Scott

Comment: TransportCredentialOnly does not work with 'https'. For 'https' you need to use Transport or TransportWithMessageCredential.

Comment: It worked! I switched it to transport and it worked flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: @JimRhodes you can write your comment as answer, in this way other users will find the solution as answered

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As per the documentation for **BasicHttpSecurityMode**, `TransportCredentialOnly` may only be used with HTTP. For HTTPS you must use either `Transport` or `TransportWithMessageCredential`.