# VS 2010 VB.NET HTTPS SERVICE REFERENCE

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a windows application that connects to a web service using http.  I have been reading a few articles on the web on how to connect using https. I've setup IIS to use the https but I can't get the application to use it. It's not a WCF service.

The error I receive when invoking the web service is

The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.
Parameter name: via

I have read that I need to add the security mode to the app.config but when I do that it doesn't change my error.

This is my app.config excerpt.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Service1SoapClient" openTimeout="00:11:00" sendTimeout="00:11:00"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="9999999"/>
        <binding>
          <security mode="Transport"></security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
         </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://lenovo-pc/service1.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="Service1SoapClient" contract="BankService.Service1Soap"
        name="Service1Soap" />
      </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Have you tried the suggested solutions posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435823/the-provided-uri-scheme-https-is-invalid-expected-http-parameter-name-via) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259364/the-provided-uri-scheme-https-is-invalid-expected-http-when-calling-web-ser)?

Comment: I believe I got it. It was a few things.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. It was a few things I went over, but ended up with the below working.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Service1SoapClient" openTimeout="00:11:00" sendTimeout="00:11:00"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="9999999">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="secureBehaviours">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://lenovo-pc/service1.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="Service1SoapClient" contract="BankService.Service1Soap"
    name="Service1Soap" />
 </client>
```