# Call WebService in https

Tags: web-services, https, web-config

I create a webService to generate pdf file. In debug mode with VisualStudio 2012. It's Ok. I can call it from other IntranetSite.

I try to put it on my test server. But I need to add https instead of http.

I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308616/vs-2010-vb-net-https-service-reference)
I try to adapted like this my web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="GenerationCourriersSoap" >
          <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
              <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
      </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
<behavior name="secureBehaviours">
  <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
</behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
 <client>
<endpoint address="https://localhost:52999/GenerationCourrier.asmx"
binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="GenerationCourriersSoap"
contract="WSCourrier.GenerationCourriersSoap" name="GenerationCourriersSoap"    />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

But I've message

> Unable to establish a trust for the secure channel SSL / TLS with authority 'localhost: 52999'.

I used an auto-certicate buid by IIS directly.
I verify, this certificate is on my root and secure folder
Someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998004/vb-net-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate)

It seems good. now I can reach the webService.

The Idea is to force the validation of all certificate. Just the time of test period like that

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates

Public Class clsSSL
    Public Function AcceptAllCertifications(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal certification As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, ByVal chain As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain, ByVal sslPolicyErrors As System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

And call function just before call WebService function

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf AcceptAllCertifications
```