# Unable to use my WebService ad Connected Service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I created a webService with Basic Authentication (using [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733775(v=vs.100).aspx)).

There is my web.config :

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="UsernameWithTransportCredentialOnly">
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="RequestUserNameConfig">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                <serviceCredentials>
                    <userNameAuthentication
                        userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                        customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyInterface.CredentialsChecker,App_Code.CredentialsChecker"/>
                </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="RequestUserNameConfig" name="MyInterface.MyService">
            <endpoint
                address="https://localhost:47336/MyService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="UsernameWithTransportCredentialOnly"
                name="BasicEndpoint"
                contract="MyInterface.IMyService">
            </endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
        multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

A folder `App_Code` contains file `CredentialsChecker.cs` with this code :

```
namespace MyInterface
{
    public class CredentialsChecker : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            /* ... Some Code ... */
        }
    }
}
```

I created a project that I want to use to test my Web Service. But When I want to add the service as service reference, I got the error :

> The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.

Did I miss something in my web service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UsernameWithTransportCredentialOnly` is of type `basicHttpBinding`. So you need to specify an endpoint that supports the binding. Either Change your address to http, or change the binding to wsHttp

```
          <endpoint
                address="http://localhost:47336/MyService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="UsernameWithTransportCredentialOnly"
                name="BasicEndpoint"
                contract="MyInterface.IMyService">
            </endpoint>
```

Comment: You right, it was a trouble with that. But to keep my https, I replaced `TransportCredentialOnly` by `TransportWithMessageCredential` (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18278320/6479770))